# List all highest datarow or spezific datarow

Tags: linq

I have a table in which I use version numbers in each row. Now I would like to have only those records that have the highest version number of a category. But there are also some records that have a negative number, -1 to be precise. These should be selected instead.

An example

```
Version number|Categegory|Name 
1             |SCHU      |Shoes 
2             |SCHU      |new shoes
1             |HAND      |Gloves 
2             |HAND      |New gloves
-1            |HAND      |New gloves V2
```

I'd like to have a list that prints the following.

```
2 |SCHU|new shoes (Secundary, Selected because max VersionNo)
-1|HAND|New Gloves V2 (Primary, Selected because Special Version)
```

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read up on LINQ? Show some C# types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an expression to modify the sort value when it is `-1` and then pick the highest value:

```
var ans = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Category"))
            .Select(rg => rg.OrderByDescending(r => r.Field<int>("VersionNumber") == -1 ? Int32.MaxValue : r.Field<int>("VersionNumber")).First());
```

Note that the result is `IEnumerable<DataRow>` and not a `DataTable`. You can use the extension `CopyToDataTable` if you want to create a new `DataTable` containing the result rows.